# Python regex, match more than one integer

Tags: python, regex

The below code prints white space and not '11' and I can't figure out why. Replacing `[0-9]*` with `[0-9]{1,2}` prints '11'. Can any one help?

```
import re
test_string = 'cake_11xlfslijg'
pattern = '.*(?P<order>[0-9]*)'
result = re.compile(pattern).search(test_string)
if result:
    print 'result'
    print result.group('order')
else:
    print result
```

Comment: Replacing `[0-9]*` with `[0-9]{1,2}` prints `1`, not `11`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `[0-9]+`. The `*` translates to *"zero or more"*, and there are zero or more digits right at the start of your string.

Comment: Quick way to show this: re.search('(.*)(\d*)', 'cake11').groups()

Comment: This will still only match `1`, not `11`, because the regex engine backtracks only as far as needed.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I've seen the `.*` only now (that's why I also wrote "at the start of the string" instead of "at the end"). Of course you are right. The regex should be `(?P<order>[0-9]+)` without the `.*`.

Answer (score 6):

Your regex should be this

```
pattern = '(?P<order>[0-9]+)'
```

1. Removed the first .* as it will do a greedy match of the entire string.
2. Made [0-9]+ as it will match the digits only even at least one is present, else it will return None.

Answer (score 1):

Because `*` means: any number of repetitions, in your regex `.*` will match all the string, because `.` means any character, i.e. including `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

A regex pattern needs to have a minimum of anchors.

With '.*' and '[0-9]*' , there are only optional symbols.

Try

```
import re

for test_string in ( 'cake_11xlfslijg',
                     'cake_uuxlfslijg'):
    pattern = '.*?(?P<order>[0-9]+)'
    result = re.compile(pattern).search(test_string)
    print test_string
    print 'result: ',repr(result.group('order')) if result else result
    print
```

gives

```
cake_11xlfslijg
result:  '11'

cake_uuxlfslijg
result:  None
```